# Java: how to do double-buffering in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, doublebuffered

**EDIT TWO**

To prevent snarky comments and one-line answers missing the point: *IFF* it is as simple as calling *setDoubleBuffered(true)*, then how do I get access to the current offline buffer so that I can start messing with the BufferedImage's underlying pixel databuffer?

I took the time to write a running piece of code (which looks kinda fun too) so I'd really appreciate answers actually answering (what a shock ;) my question and explaining what/how this is working instead of one-liners and snarky comments ;)

Here's a working piece of code that bounces a square across a JFrame. I'd like to know about the various ways that can be used to transform this piece of code  so that it uses double-buffering.

Note that the way I clear the screen and redraw the square ain't the most efficient but this is really not what this question is about (in a way, it's better for the sake of this example that it is somewhat slow).

Basically, I need to constantly modify a lot pixels in a BufferedImage (as to have some kind of animation) and I don't want to see the visual artifacts due to single-buffering on screen.

I've got a JLabel whose Icon is an ImageIcon wrapping a BufferedImage.  I want to modify that BufferedImage.

What has to be done so that this becomes double-buffered?

I understand that somehow *"image 1"* will be shown while I'll be drawing on *"image 2"*. But then once I'm done drawing on *"image 2"*, how do I "quickly" replace *"image 1"* by *"image 2"*?

Is this something I should be doing manually, like, say, by swapping the JLabel's ImageIcon myself?

Should I be always drawing in the same BufferedImage then do a fast 'blit' of that BufferedImage's pixels in the JLabel's ImageIcon's BufferedImage? (I guess no and I don't see how I could "synch" this with the monitor's "vertical blank line" [or equivalent in flat-screen: I mean, to 'synch' without interfering with the moment the monitor itselfs refreshes its pixels, as to prevent shearing]).

What about the "repaint" orders? Am I suppose to trigger these myself? Which/when exactly should I call *repaint()* or something else?

The most important requirement is that I should be modifying pixels directly in the images's pixel databuffer.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

public class DemosDoubleBuffering extends JFrame {

    private static final int WIDTH  = 600;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;

    int xs = 3;
    int ys = xs;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    final int r = 80;

    final BufferedImage bi1;

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final DemosDoubleBuffering frame = new DemosDoubleBuffering();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public DemosDoubleBuffering() {
        super( "Trying to do double buffering" );
        final JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        bi1 = new BufferedImage( WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        final Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while ( true ) {
                    move();
                    drawSquare( bi1 );
                    jl.repaint();
                    try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        jl.setIcon( new ImageIcon( bi1 ) );
        getContentPane().add( jl );
    }

    private void drawSquare( final BufferedImage bi ) {
        final int[] buf = ((DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            buf[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;    // clearing all white
        }
        for (int xx = 0; xx < r; xx++) {
            for (int yy = 0; yy < r; yy++) {
                buf[WIDTH*(yy+y)+xx+x] = 0xFF000000;
            }
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        if ( !(x + xs >= 0 && x + xs + r < bi1.getWidth()) ) {
            xs = -xs;
        }
        if ( !(y + ys >= 0 && y + ys + r < bi1.getHeight()) ) {
            ys = -ys;
        }
        x += xs;
        y += ys;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

This is **not** for a full-screen Java application, but a regular Java application, running in its own (somewhat small) window.

Comment: Swing is double buffered by default. This is not AWT.

Comment: Still waiting for someone to post actual code that we can test to see if double buffering is worth the effort.

Comment: I guess you have misunderstood swing. You can't access the (unmodified) offline buffer. Swing will past the buffer to your parent, and your parent will modify it. ... To do what you want, you have to *disable* swing doublebuffering and do it with, say, BufferedImage. If you want to do real "bitblt", you have to use "heavy-weight" component in AWT.

Answer (score 14):

---- Edited to address per pixel setting ----

The item blow addresses double buffering, but there's also an issue on how to get pixels into a `BufferedImage`.

If you call

```
WriteableRaster raster = bi.getRaster()
```

on the `BufferedImage` it will return a `WriteableRaster`.  From there you can use

```
int[] pixels = new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
// code to set array elements here
raster.setPixel(0, 0, pixels);
```

Note that you would probably want to optimize the code to not actually create a new array for each rendering.  In addition, you would probably want to optimized the array clearing code to not use a for loop.

```
Arrays.fill(pixels, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

would probably outperform your loop setting the background to white.

---- Edited after response ----

The key is in your original setup of the JFrame and inside the run rendering loop.

First you need to tell SWING to stop Rasterizing whenever it wants to; because, you'll be telling it when you're done drawing to the buffered image you want to swap out in full.  Do this with JFrame's

```
setIgnoreRepaint(true);
```

Then you'll want to create a buffer strategy.  Basically it specifies how many buffers you want to use

```
createBufferStrategy(2);
```

Now that you tried to create the buffer strategy, you need to grab the `BufferStrategy` object as you will need it later to switch buffers.

```
final BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = getBufferStrategy();
```

Inside your `Thread` modify the `run()` loop to contain:

```
...
  move();
  drawSqure(bi1);
  Graphics g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
  g.drawImage(bi1, 0, 0, null);
  g.dispose();
  bufferStrategy.show();
...
```

The graphics grabbed from the bufferStrategy will be the off-screen `Graphics` object, when creating triple buffering, it will be the "next" off-screen `Graphics` object in a round-robin fashion.

The image and the Graphics context are not related in a containment scenario, and you told Swing you'd do the drawing yourself, so you have to draw the image manually.  This is not always a bad thing, as you can specify the buffer flipping when the image is fully drawn (and not before).

Disposing of the graphics object is just a good idea as it helps in garbage collection.  Showing the `bufferStrategy` will flip buffers.

While there might have been a misstep somewhere in the above code, this should get you 90% of the way there.  Good luck!

---- Original post follows ----

It might seem silly to refer such a question to a javase tutorial, but have you looked into [`BufferStrategy` and `BufferCapatbilites`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)?

The main issue I think you are encountering is that you are fooled by the name of the Image.  A `BufferedImage` has nothing to do with double buffering, it has to do with "buffering the data (typically from disk) in memory."  As such, you will need two BufferedImages if you wish to have a "double buffered image"; as it is unwise to alter pixels in image which is being shown (it might cause repainting issues).

In your rendering code, you grab the graphics object.  If you set up double buffering according to the tutorial above, this means you will grab (by default) the off-screen `Graphics` object, and all drawing will be off-screen.  Then you draw your image (the right one of course) to the off-screen object.  Finally, you tell the strategy to `show()` the buffer, and it will do the replacement of the Graphics context for you.

Comment: @Edwin Buck: +1 for the help but I don't use BufferedImage because the name would be fooling me: I'm using them because the ability to manipulate pixels directly in the image is a requirement and the only way I know to get access to an image's underlying pixel databuffer is to use a BufferedImage.

Comment: @SpoonBender well, I was a bit off in thinking you'd need two BufferedImages, actually you can get by with just one because you need to draw it to each buffer individually.  I updated my post giving details on how to possibly integrate Swing's double buffering support into you example.

Comment: This is perhaps a better strategy then the one I posted. This same technique is also used by Canvas class for multiple buffers as well (and I think this is the technique that I used a long time ago on an animation project for my students in Java).

Comment: @SpoonBender added a bit about setting the pixels.  The key is to use a Raster object (which conceptually contains the pixels) and just clobber the BufferedImage's internal Raster by setting it in bulk.

Comment: @Edwin Buck: thanks a lot.  The part about setting ignoreRepainting and why is **very** interesting :)

Comment: @SpoonBender: Do you think you may have been double buffered before and by virtue of the Rasterizer running whenever it wanted, you were picking up the image before it was fully drawn?  That would be a new twist on things!

Answer (score 3):

Generally we use Canvas class which is suitable for animation in Java. Anyhoo, following is how you achieve double buffering:

```
class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {
  private Image dbImage;
  private Graphics dbg; 
  int x_pos, y_pos;

  public CustomCanvas () {

  }

  public void update (Graphics g) {
    // initialize buffer
    if (dbImage == null) {

      dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
      dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();

    }

    // clear screen in background
    dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
    dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

    // draw elements in background
    dbg.setColor (getForeground());
    paint (dbg);

    // draw image on the screen
    g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this); 
  }

        public void paint (Graphics g)
 {

        g.setColor  (Color.red);



        g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    }
}
```

Now you can update the x_pos and y_pos from a thread, followed by the 'repaint' call on the canvas object. The same technique should work on a JPanel as well.

Comment: @Usman Saleem: Hi Saleem, it's great to see a newcomer helping here :)  When working with a Canvas, can I also access the pixels's databuffer in the same way I do with a BufferedImage?

Comment: Shouldn't the repaint call be issued in the EDT ?

Comment: But there is not need for this. Swing allows animation as well. That is not double buffering. Or if it is the same code can be used on a Swing JPanel since all you are doing is drawing an image.

Comment: @Usman Saleem: the technique you showed is using one back buffer in which you do all the drawing, then a "blit" using *g.drawIamge(...)* right?

Comment: @camickr: using a backbuffer then a blit like Usman Saleem posted *is* one kind of double buffering.  It is actually the one explained in the Oracle/Sun article on Double Buffering (which sadly is too short of an article).  the 'dbg' is the back buffer and the 'g' is the main buffer.  That is two buffer, that is (one kind of) double buffering.

Comment: @sb: Right, the idea is while foreground is busy in rendering the image on container's graphics object, the background is preparing it in the bufferimage's graphics object. We usually have to introduce some Thread.sleep in the thread responsible for updating x,y so that there is some interleaving involved.

Comment: @SpoonBender, Have you got this example working yet? I would like to compare this animation with yours or trashgod's animation to see the difference.

Comment: @SB: For your first comment, I think the actual image returned from canvas' createImage is a BufferedImage. You can test it with instanceof to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation in which all drawing takes place on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Addendum:

> Basically, I need to constantly modify a lot pixels in a `BufferedImage`…

This [kinetic model](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) illustrates several approaches to pixel animation.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356 */
public class DemosDoubleBuffering extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final int W = 600;
    private static final int H = 400;
    private static final int r = 80;
    private int xs = 3;
    private int ys = xs;
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;
    private final BufferedImage bi;
    private final JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    private final Timer t  = new Timer(10, this);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new DemosDoubleBuffering());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public DemosDoubleBuffering() {
        super(true);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(W, H));
        bi = new BufferedImage(W, H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
        this.add(jl);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        move();
        drawSquare(bi);
        jl.repaint();
    }

    private void drawSquare(final BufferedImage bi) {
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(x, y, r, r);
        g.dispose();
    }

    private void move() {
        if (!(x + xs >= 0 && x + xs + r < bi.getWidth())) {
            xs = -xs;
        }
        if (!(y + ys >= 0 && y + ys + r < bi.getHeight())) {
            ys = -ys;
        }
        x += xs;
        y += ys;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is basically impossible in windowed mode with Swing. There is no support for raster synchronization for window repaints, this is only available in fullscreen mode (and even then may not be supported by all platforms).

Swing components are double-buffered by default, that is they will do all the rendering to an intermediate buffer and that buffer is then finally copied to the screen, avoiding flicker from background clearing and then painting on top of it.
And thats the only strategy that is reasonable well supported on all underlying platforms. It avoids  only repaint flickering, but not visual tearing from moving graphic elements.

A reasonably simple way of having access to the raw pixels of an area fully under you control would be to extend a custom component from JComponent and overwrite its paintComponent()-method to paint the area from a BufferedImage (from memory):

```
public class PixelBufferComponent extends JComponent {

    private BufferedImage bufferImage;

    public PixelBufferComponent(int width, int height) {
        bufferImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bufferImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

You can then manipulate you buffered image whichever way you desire. To get your changes made visible on screen, simply call repaint() on it. If you do the pixel manipulation from a thread other than the EDT, you need TWO buffered images to cope with race conditions between the actual repaint and your manipulation thread.

Note that this skeleton will not paint the entire area of the component when used with a layout manager that stretches the component beyond its preferred size.

Note also, the buffered image approach mostly only makes sense if you do real low level pixel manipulation via setRGB(...) on the image or if you directly access the underlying DataBuffer directly. If you can do all the manipulations using Graphics2D's methods, you could do all the stuff in the paintComponent method using the provided graphics (which is actually a Graphics2D and can be simply casted).