# Anti-aliasing in paintComponent() method

Tags: java, string, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

I want to print some text using the `paintComponent(..)` method.

```
@Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("Hello world", 10, 10);
}
```

But the text is somewhat jaggy. 
How could you force text drawing with [anti-aliasing] in this method?

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean anti-aliasing rather than double buffering?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set double buffering by:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel() {
        super(true);//set Double buffering for JPanel
    }
}
```

or simply call  [`JComponent#setDoubleBuffered(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29).

You can also set `RenderingHint`s for `Graphics2D` objects like *anti-aliasing* and *text anti-aliasing* to improve Swing painting quality by:

```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    //Set  anti-alias!
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); 

   // Set anti-alias for text
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON); 

    graphics2D.setColor(Color.red);
    graphics2D.drawString("Hello world", 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove the double buffering part from the answer to avoid confusion. For that, there are [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing).

Comment: Is it enough to set this in the constructor of the JPanel or do I have to set this strategy in every call to paintComponent?

Comment: You wouldn't have access to the graphics object in the constructor.