# Ugly Fonts in Java Swing - How to set antialiasing?

Tags: java, swing, antialiasing

I'm creating a modern-looking program with a cool GUI, but Java prevents me from doing that by showing a eye-burning text presentation.

Here's how it looks like:
[image].

Look at the numbers, they are shaped horribly.

I'm using a custom font too, Montserrat, which is known for being modern and smooth-edged, but Java ruins it.

(The component used to display those numbers is a JFreeChart, so I can't know which component is used precisely, but I assume it's a JLabel)

I already tried:

- Activating anti-aliasing with
  `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");`, `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","lcd");` and
  `System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");`,
  but none of them worked.
- Replacing the paintComponent of the component I'm using to render those numbers with:

```
ChartPanel graficoInnerPanel = new ChartPanel(grafico){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anti-aliasing in paintComponent() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236797/anti-aliasing-in-paintcomponent-method)

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html You might also try things like `VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_GASP` - specifically, there's an example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/examples/AntialiasedText.java)

Comment: If a descendant of your ChartPanel is not using antialiasing, you probably need to override [paintChildren](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintChildren(java.awt.Graphics)) rather than paintComponent.  And your override should set the text antialiasing rendering hint before calling super.paintChildren.

Comment: @vgr override paint by setting anti-aliasing properties of the Graphics passed and then call paintComponent, paintBorder and then paintChildren with the same modified graphics? Wasn't it the best to do?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès ChartPanel doesn’t seem to do any painting of its own, and the border doesn’t need to be antialiased, so overriding paintComponent and paintBorder seems pointless.