# Simple custom painting mistake

Tags: java, swing, awt, double-buffering

I just started coding again and I guess I forgot how to double buffer. This is the code I have now and I'm not sure what I am missing. When I start it there is just a white screen, no oval.

What is the mistake in rendering?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Graphs extends JFrame {

private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Graphs();
}

public Graphs() {
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Graphs");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    dbg.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawOval(200, 200, 200, 200);
    repaint();
}
}
```

### Update: compilation error on `@Override`

```
The method  paintComponent(Graphics) of type Graphs must override or implement a supertype method.

1 quick fix available:
-> Remove '@Override' annotation
```

Comment: Looks like [DUPLICATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing)

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` - Make that `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` for a surprise!  Tip:  Do custom painting in a `JPanel` instead.  Add that to the top-level container.

Comment: add an @Override annotation to the method paintComponent? http://prntscr.com/q7dit

Comment: Please don't post images of your IDE (or links to them). Copy/paste the error and code as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14492528/edit).

Comment: Sorry sir... I was just trying to show you that the "surprise" I received from your suggestion gave me an error. I have already tried adding an @Override annotation to the paint method as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: That was intended as 'zen advice' to lead you to the understanding of why the `@Override` notation is important - for finding out when you *think* you are overriding an existing method, but are *actually* creating a ***new*** method!  +1 for posting code in which the problems were obvious & in accepting an answer promptly.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you're not seeing the oval is that you're drawing the image onto its own `Graphics` object. Replace:

```
dbg.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
```

with

```
g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
```

Also better not to override `paint` in a top-level container but rather override `paintComponent` in a sub-classed `JComponent`. Also remember to call

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should avoid overriding the `paint` method of top level
   components (like `JFrame`), the main issue for you is that they are 
   not double buffered, like components that extend from `JComponent`
2. Failing to call `super.paint` is VERY, VERY bad.  You've basically prevent the frame from painting any of its child components...
3. You shouldn't be loading images within the `paint` method, it will slow down any future repaints
4. You should never call `repaint` from any `paintXxx` method, it will cause an infinite loop of paints to be created, quickly devouring your CPU cycles
5. `JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` method.
6. It is preferred that custom painting be performed an `JComponent` (such as a `JPanel`) via the `paintComponent` method.

**Update with Example**

[image]

```
public class BadPaint10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadPaint10();
    }

    public BadPaint10() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PaintPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PaintPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public PaintPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/shane/Dropbox/pictures/436px-Work_with_exotic_creatures.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g.drawImage(background, x, y, this);

                x = (getWidth() - 200) / 2;
                y = (getHeight() - 200) / 2;
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawOval(x, y, 200, 200);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

As has already been noted, precedence is important.  The order that elements are paint will effect the out come.

You might find

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Useful.