# Layered Canvas in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, graphics2d

I am simulating *persons* walking on a graph of connected nodes. To display it visually I use the canvas object. I do that by first rendering the graph with it's nodes and links between them, after that I start drawing the *person* which is represented by a little square moving through the graph.

My problem is that after I draw the map (or graph) the person's animation deletes the labels and sometimes lines of the graph. I know that this is because I render the person's movement
on the same canvas that contains the map (and because of the `clearRect()` method call).

How can I avoid clearing the graph?, at first I looked at the `JLayeredPane` but the canvases overlap and there's no transparency (without trans-parenting the person) on the topmost canvas. The second option that I thought of is to copy the area before drawing the person and then restoring the area when the person moves, but I'm not sure how to achieve this so guidance is appreciated as I haven't used `swing` or `awt` that much and I think this might be a common problem.

I've attached an image to show my issue and my rendering code for each *person*

```
public class Person extends Thread {

    public Person(String name, Spot location, World world, Graphics g) {
    this.name= name;
    this.location= location;
    this.world= world;
    this.g= g;
}

private void move() {
    Set<Link> links= world.getLinksFrom(location.getId());  
Link route= CollectionUtil.getRandomElement(links);  
Spot destination= route.getOriginX() == location.getX() &&   
    route.getOriginY() == location.getY() ?  
    route.getTheTarget(): route.getTheOrigin();  

try {
    double deltaX= (destination.getX() - location.getX()) / route.distance();
    double deltaY= (destination.getY() - location.getY()) / route.distance();
    double w2= (PERSON_WIDTH / 2);

    for(double i=location.getX(), j=location.getY(), d= route.distance(); 
    d > 5;
    i+=deltaX, j+= deltaY, 
    d=Point2D.distance(i, j, destination.getX(), destination.getY())) {
            g.clearRect((int)(i - w2 - deltaX), (int)(j - w2 - deltaY), 
        PERSON_WIDTH, PERSON_WIDTH);
        g.drawRect((int)(i-w2), (int)(j-w2), 
        PERSON_WIDTH-1, PERSON_WIDTH-1);
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }

    this.location= destination;

    // Stay ath the new location for a while
    Thread.sleep(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(Person.MAX_SPOT_MILLIS));
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    while(!isInterrupted()) {
        this.move();            
    }
}
}
```

[image: My rendering Problem]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There's not enough information to go on, but, it looks like your storing a reference to the graphics object, possibly by using getGraphics. This is not a good idea. The graphics context returned by getGraohics can be null and changed between repaints. You also appear to be updating the UI out side the event Dispathing thread. This is also a bad idea as you don't actually control when repaints occur and could produce paint artifacts. Take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: You are correct on everything that you assumed (`getGraphics` reference, each person is a `Thread`), thanks for the link I'll see if I can set up a SSCCE as @AndreThompson points out.

Comment: use JLayer/GlassPane for painting on top of

Comment: don't block EDT by Thread.sleep(int), nor for OpenGL/CL

Comment: @mKorbel What do you mean by EDT?, would you use a JInternalFrame for that?

Comment: [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), I'm wouldn't be use a JInternalFrame, no reason to create MDI like as (from) Atari times

Answer (score 1):

The two most common solutions are:

1. Draw the graph every time. Use [double buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing) to avoid flicker. Unless your graph has a lot of nodes and you have a very slow computer, this should work well.
2. Render the graph into an image. Before you start painting the persons, draw the image once. This clears the whole canvas.

Comment: I'm unsure if the OP is using java.awt.Canvas or not. If they are, the it becomes a question of why? Swing components are double buffered by default. The second point is an excellent suggestion regardless

Answer (score 1):

1. Unless you create it yourself, you should not be maintaining a reference to the `Graphics` context. The graphics context can be changed between repaints and repaints will override anything painted to it in between. You should overriding the `paintComponet` method of a custom component (like `JPanel`) and painting the current state of the component on each invocation
2. It sounds like your are using `java.awt.Canvas`, you should avoid AWT and use Swing instead. It's a more up to date framework and is double buffered by default. You should avoid mixing AWT and Swing components as they tend not to play nice together
3. Swing is a single threaded environment, meaning that you should only interact with the UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread? Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.
4. There are 3 ways to do animation Swing. You can use a `Thread` or a `javax.swing.Timer` or one of the animation frameworks.

Using Threads is more complex and makes you responsible for ensuring that updates are correctly resynced by to the client.  This is useful for complex animation jobs, where the time between calculating the state on each cycle my vary.

`javax.swing.Timer` is simpler, as it's callback is executed within the context of the EDT at regular intervals. It's great for simple animations where the time it takes to update the state are short and/or reasonable constant so that they won't have the potential of causing staggering frames

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try having two canvases then I think I may have a solution.

Create your first canvas that will draw your graph and create a canvas on top of that that will draw your people.

You can set the background colour of the top canvas to be a clear colour and then also clear the canvas with that same clear colour.

For example:

```
g.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

will clear the top canvas leaving a completely transparent colour behind

```
canvas.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0);
```

will make the canvas component transparent. **This only needs to be called once when you are creating the canvas.**

Now the top canvas will be completely transparent after your clear it with the 0 alpha colour and only what you draw on the top canvas will block out the bottom canvas.

Hope this helps

Comment: If the OP is using AWT components, this has the potentional of causing paint artifacts as, if I'm not mistaken, AWT components don't support transparency and the repaint manager won't know to update the components beneth it. If the OP issuing Swing components, then they should be setting the componet transparent via the setOpaque method, which tells the repaint manager that the components below it also need to be updated

Comment: I guess what I was thinking of was a more complex answer then I realized. I was thinking of having 2 classes extending swing JPanels and running off their own timers. This way they could be managed individually with their transparency settings. I tried this using multiple panels created from separate threads. It worked like I thought though the performance hit is just too much. Multiple graphics contexts from different threads means I need a lot of synchronization and it's really an over complex solution to a simpler problem.