# JComponent is blinking while painting BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

There is this `JFrame` holding `JComponent` that being drawn `30` times a second. The problem appears to be with flashing or blinking effect when drawing the `BufferedImage` like it gets drawn on each other un-accordingly..

Also, There is a second problem wheres the Window constructor is executing really late, sometimes when the program actually need to use this object if `EventQueue.invokeLater` is applied, is it critical to have it there or leave it the way it is?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Window{

    private JFrame window;
    private CanvasComponent component;

    public Window(Input input){

        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int hostMonitorWidth = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int hostMonitorHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

        window = new JFrame();
        component = new CanvasComponent(hostMonitorWidth, hostMonitorHeight);

        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,200));
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        window.setSize(hostMonitorWidth, hostMonitorHeight);
        window.getContentPane().add(component);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.requestFocus();
        window.setFocusableWindowState(true);

        window.addKeyListener(input);

    }

    public void draw(){
        component.draw();
    }

    private class CanvasComponent extends JComponent{

        public CanvasComponent(int hostMonitorWidth, int hostMonitorHeight){
            super.setSize(hostMonitorWidth, hostMonitorHeight);
            super.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
            super.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(GraphicsBatch == null) return;

            BufferedImage image = GraphicsBatch.getImage();
            g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        }

        public void draw(){
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    repaint();
                }});
        }
    }
}
```

`Window.draw()` is being called 30 times a sec.

Comment: Related answers and question: [Java: how to do double-buffering in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing) You need to turn on double buffering.

Comment: @Ferrybig i have already tried `setDoubleBuffered(true)` but it has no effect, how else can i apply double buffering?

Comment: Can we see the source of `GraphicsBatch.getImage();`? How are the images generated in here? (Cached image, Image from network, image loaded from file, etc)

Comment: Set the `ImageObserver` from `null` to `this`, and consider making a member variable for your image and initializing it in the constructor; you can use this variable in `g.drawImage` so that you don't unnecessarily create and load another image each time `paintComponent` is executed.

Comment: `Window.draw()` _is being called 30 times a sec_. Where? On the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)?

Comment: @Ferrybig Swing components are double buffered by default

Comment: @trashgod No. though on `CanvasComponent` it's in the EDT. However, i have tried running Window.draw() through the EDT and it has no effect.

Comment: @Ferrybig It's a class with buffered image and it's raster, nothing special. if it could help i can bring it on here.