# Moving draw on Jcomponent

Tags: java, swing, repaint, jcomponent

I want to draw a moving cursor (in green) in my 2D plan view (in red) . I use a joystick to command it.

To access to the red panel I have to get components of components from the controller following this scheme :
JPanel => JScrollPane => JViewPort => PlanComponent (extends JComponent)

My cursor coordinates are continuously updated by reading a socket.
When the coordinates are changed, it calls the drawCross fonction.

My cursor is perfectly moved by the joystick but the red area blinks and the cursor blinks over more.

[Coloured program screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1scg.png)

```
 public ThreadGestionObjetImu(Home home, HomeController homeController) {
    _sweetHome3dHomeControllerVar = homeController;
    _jComponentLayer1 = (MultipleLevelsPlanPanel) _sweetHome3dHomeControllerVar.getPlanController().getView();
    _jComponentLayer2 = (JPanel) _jComponentLayer1.getComponent(1);
    _jComponentLayer3 = (JScrollPane) _jComponentLayer2.getComponent(0);
    _jComponentLayer4 = (JViewport) _jComponentLayer3.getComponent(0);
    _planComponent = (PlanComponent) _jComponentLayer4.getComponent(0);
}


public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    //parsing socket signal
    switch(XImuPlugin.state){
        case PLAN:
            drawCross();
            break;
    }
}



public void drawCross() {
    _planComponent.getGraphics().drawLine(_crossPositionX + _intImuValueX, _crossPositionY + 25 + _intImuValueY, _crossPositionX + 50 + _intImuValueX, _crossPositionY + 25 + _intImuValueY);
    _planComponent.getGraphics().drawLine(_crossPositionX + 25 + _intImuValueX, _crossPositionY + _intImuValueY, _crossPositionX + 25 + _intImuValueX, _crossPositionY + 50 + _intImuValueY);

    if (_intImuValueX > 1 || _intImuValueX < -1 || _intImuValueY > 1 || _intImuValueY < -1) {
        _planComponent.update(_planComponent.getGraphics());
        // I tried update, repaint, updateUI and all the possible functions
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I forgot to precise that I was stuck in only using the sweetHome3D Api because I'm creating a plug-in, I can't modify the original code.

Problem solved by using _planComponent.add(MyComponent);
I created a JComponent with an override of paintComponent.

Comment: Please simplify your problem and your code by creating and posting a suitable [mcve].

Comment: `_planComponent.getGraphics()` that looks suspicious.. Will know more when the MCVE suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels is posted.

Comment: Tried to be clearer, don't hesitate to ask for details.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a know problem, if you draw in a component already in the UI the result is this blinking (the component drawing his background color and then drawing the image).

To avoid that, you can use a "double buffer", drawing the new image in a hide image and then, when it is ready replace directly in your UI.

A nice explanation can be found in [oracle doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html)

And an example here in [stackoverflow: double buffering in java SWING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430356/java-how-to-do-double-buffering-in-swing)

Comment: Swing is double buffered by default. The problem is the usage of the getGraphics() method. Don't use getGraphcis(). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method.